# How to remove all lowercase characters from a string using AWK?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

Please note that I need this answer in AWK.

How can I remove all lowercase characters from some awk variable? I tried calling gsub:

`gsub(/[a-z]+/,"",varName);`

Unfortunately, that removes the whole string, as if awk cannot tell the difference between lower and upper case. Is there some regex-fu I can use that I'm not aware of?

EDIT: Confirmed, awk does not see the difference between lowercase and uppercase characters.

Example 1 (will use letter f here for better understanding of results):

```
varName="CHRFProtocol";
gsub(/[a-z]/,"f",varName);
```

Result: `ffffffffffff`

Example 2 (again, will use letter f here for better understanding of results):

```
varName="CHRFProtocol";
gsub(/[A-Z]/,"f",varName);
```

Result: `ffffffffffff`

Is this legitimate? What's doing on?

Comment: What happens when you try sub with the same regex?

Comment: @connor Only the first character is replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your locale settings are getting in the way.  Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN { 
varName="CHRFProtocol";
gsub(/[a-z]/,"f",varName);
print(varName); }'
```

GNU awk honors locale settings, and in most national locales on Linux, regular expressions are case-insensitive.   Resetting the locale to `C` (=`POSIX`) for the duration of the `awk` command restores case-sensitivity.

Comment: Shit. I would've NEVER guessed that. My hat's off to you good sir. :)

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: What do your locale settings look like? I have `"en_US.utf8"`, and it works for me (i.e., awk distinguishes between lowercase and uppercase letters).

Comment: @KeithThompson it seems to be dependent on both implementation and platform.  Based on my testing, the case-insensitivity shows up only in gawk (not original or BSD awk, mawk, or nawk) and, even in gawk, only on Linux (not OS X).

Comment: Right reason, but wrong solution - setting LC_ALL to C will affect other, possibly undesirable, things like the separator in thousands being comma vs period. All that's needed here is to test for `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[a-z]`.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point, but I'd say that if you're only setting it for the duration of an awk one-liner, it's not likely to matter.

Comment: @MarkReed - I'm taking about it's effect inside the awk command, e.g. if you're working with numbers greater than 1,000. You're right it probably wont matter, but why not just use the POSIX character class which is briefer, simpler, and you KNOW won't have any undesirable side-effects?

Answer (score 3):

You should just be using the POSIX character class [[:lower:]], not [a-z]:

```
gsub(/[[:lower:]]/,"",varName)
```

The latter is locale-dependent, the former is not.

It seems like there's some confusion over when to use POSIX character classes vs when/how to set locale so:

1) Always use POSIX character classes when they exist for the character set you're interested in (e.g. [:digit:], [:lower:], [:punct:], etc., etc.)

2) Otherwise, set LC_ALL=C IF you're OK with how that affects your other settings (e.g. comma vs period as the thousands separator)

3) Otherwise, set LC_COLLATE=C.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html for more info on character classes and locale variables.

Comment: Good point, however how this gsub should be written if requirement is to replace all US english letters between `c-l` ?

Comment: Set the locale to one that behaves as desired and use /[c-l]/ or use /[cdefghijkl]/.

Comment: Hmm that's indeed the answer posted by @MarkReed

Comment: Yes, but it's the answer to a different question. It also doesn't say you need to set LC_ALL, though that is often the right approach when you need to set locale.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all lowercase characters in awk, use :

```
gsub(/[a-z]+/, "", varName);
```

You're actually replacing 1 or more occurrence of lowercase alphabets with literal string `"f"`

**EDIT After you've corrected your question:**

Note that if your `varName` only contains lowercase alphabets or is already empty then you will get an empty string in `varName`.

Comment: I was aware of that, what I meant was is there a regex statement that would substitute LOWERCASE characters only?

Comment: So you want to replace lowercase alphabets with some string "F"? That you were already doing in `gsub(/[a-z]+/, "F", varName);` earlier

Comment: Remove lowercase characters altogether. I only used 'f' for testing purposes, and forgot to remove it during question writeup. :(

Comment: Sorry, but that just replaces the whole string with nothing. And it DEFINITELY contains both lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: I have tested it again on a mixed case string and it replaced only lowercase characters. Can you provide some small test data and your full awk command.

Comment: I tested this code: `awk 'BEGIN{varName="CHRFProtocol"; gsub(/[a-z]/,"f",varName); print varName}'` and I get `CHRFPfffffff` as output.

Comment: The posted script does not remove all lower-case letters, it removes all letter between `a` and `z` in the current locale so if in your locale letters are ordered as `aAbB...zZ`, for example, then the letter `Z` would not be removed bu all other letters (`a`, `A`, `b`, `B`, etc) would be removed. To remove all lower case letters use `/[[:lower:]]/`.

Answer (score 1):

example explains everything:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{var="AaBbCcDDDdddEEEeee";print "before:"var;gsub(/[a-z]/,"",var);print "after:"var}' 
before:AaBbCcDDDdddEEEeee
after:ABCDDDEEE
```

Comment: try this to see if it gave you different output: `awk -v IGNORECASE=0 'your awk code here'` @S.T.A.L.K.E.R.

Comment: Nope, same result. Locale setting fixed this.